# erlang - inspect mailbox messages once at a time

Tags: erlang

I am trying to inspect the messages a node receives from other nodes, but in some other manner other than `flush()`, because the message size is rather big and it doesn't help. Also, I can see the messages with `erlang:process_info(self(), messages_queue_len).`, but I would like some way of extracting one message at a time in some kind of variable for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`receive` is the erlang primitive for taking messages from the mailbox.

See:  http://www.erlang.org/doc/getting_started/conc_prog.html#id2263965

If you just want to get the first message in the shell for debugging, you could try defining a fun like this:

```
1> self() ! foo.
foo
2> F = fun() -> receive X -> X end end.
#Fun<erl_eval.20.67289768>
3> F().
foo
```

Answer (score 7):

You might want to have a look to the `dbg` module in Erlang.

Start the tracer:

```
dbg:tracer().
```

Trace all messages received (r) by a process (in this case self()):

```
dbg:p(self(), r).
```

More information [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/dbg.html#p-2).

Answer (score 2):

or you can use:

```
1> F = fun() -> receive X -> {message, X} after 0 -> no_message end end.
#Fun<erl_eval.20.111823515>
2> F().
no_message
3> self() ! foo.
foo
4> self() ! bar.
bar
5> F().
{message, foo}
6> F().
{message, bar}
```

... to prevent blocking